# oozie: add a file tag to a workflow.xml

Tags: python, apache-spark, oozie, hue

I'm trying to build a oozie job with a python spark action and to do so I need to add a file tag `<file> /path/to/myfile.py <file>` into my workflow.xml. I only have access to a HUE interface (3.7.0) and I can't use a CLI.

P.S I have no problem to do that with a shell script since an input box is directly available during the shell action definition.

Comment: There is no `<file>` element in a Spark action, as of Oozie 4.2 *(XML schema V0.1)* - look by yourself in the documentation https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SparkActionExtension.html#Spark_Action_Schema_Version_0.1

Comment: You will need to add the file in the action that is using it indeed.